# How to calculate the variance of fixed effects Panel data model with measurement error ( attenuation bias)

Tags: time-series, variance, econometrics, panel-data, measurement-error

Consider the following model
\begin{align} 
y_{i t}& =\beta x_{i t}+\varepsilon_{i t} \\\\ 
\Delta y_{i t}&=\beta \Delta x_{i t}+\Delta \varepsilon_{i t} \\\\
\tilde{x}_{it} &= x _{i t} + u _{i t} \\\\
\text{where} \\\\
x _{i t}&=\rho x _{i t-1}+v _{i t} \\\\
u _{i t}&=r u _{i t-1}+e _{i t} 
\end{align}

According to the notes I'm following, we can calculate

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\Delta x}^2=\operatorname{var}\left(x_t\right)-2 \operatorname{cov}\left(x_{i t}, x_{i t-1}\right)+\operatorname{var}\left(x_{i t-1}\right)=2 \sigma_x^2-2 \operatorname{cov}\left(x_{i t}, x_{i t-1}\right) = 2 \sigma_x^2(1-\rho)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\Delta u}^2=\operatorname{var}\left(u_t\right)-2 \operatorname{cov}\left(u_{i t}, u_{i t-1}\right)+\operatorname{var}\left(u_{i t-1}\right)=2 \sigma_u^2-2 \operatorname{cov}\left(u_{i t}, u_{i t-1}\right) = 2 \sigma_u^2(1-r)
\end{equation}

Then the attenuation bias can be written

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{plim} \widehat{\beta}=\beta\left(\frac{\sigma_x^2(1-\rho)}{\sigma_x^2(1-\rho)+\sigma_u^2(1-r)}\right)=\beta\left(\frac{1}{1+\sigma_u^2(1-r) / \sigma_\chi^2(1-\rho)}\right)
\end{equation}

I'm a bit lost on how to calculate the two variances $\sigma_{\Delta x}^2$ and $\sigma_{\Delta u}^2$. I think it should be fairly straightforward, but I'm not great at calculating variances.

I'll try to specify the parts that I find confusing:

1. Where do I start exactly? I guess I need to find the expression of $\Delta x$?
2. Maybe this will become clear after I solve the first steps, but I don't understand the simplification in the second and third equality in $\sigma_{\Delta x}^2$
3. Is $\tilde{x}_{it}$ is used in the derivation? Is this just $x _{it}$ with the measurement error added?

The derivation of $\sigma_{\Delta u}^2$ is identical to $\sigma_{\Delta x}^2$ obviously.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Let me know if you need additional information!